# Error resolving ActionFilterAttribute as TypeFilter in .net Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Updating my application from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1 I get an error trying to resolve a dependency of an ActionFilter.

I have this filter

```
public class DoSomethingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IWorkContext workContext;

        public OneEnum OneParameter { get; set; }

        public AuthorizeAdminAttribute(OneEnum oneParameter, IWorkContext workContext)
        {
            OneParameter = oneParameter;
            workContext = workContext;
        }

         /**more stuff**/
    }
```

I registered it

```
services.AddScoped<DoSomethingAttribute>();
```

And I called it

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Authorize]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [TypeFilter(typeof(DoSomethingAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { OneEnum.OneValue } )]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {}
```

With .Net core 2.2 version it was working but with 3.1 I get this error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: DoSomethingAttribute Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: DoSomethingAttribute': Unable to resolve service for type 'POneEnum' while attempting to activate 'DoSomethingAttribute'.

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'OneEnum' while attempting to activate 'DoSomethingAttribute'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just remove services.AddScoped<DoSomethingAttribute>() this line and you will see your error is disappear and IWorkContext will auto injection by asp.net core.

Comment: thank you @Changemyminds, that was the solution

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo like below:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyFilterAttribute(params object[] arguments) : base(typeof(DoSomethingAttribute))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { arguments };
    }

    public class DoSomethingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        private readonly IWorkContext WorkContext;
        private readonly OneEnum OneParameter;
 
        public DoSomethingAttribute(object[] arguments, IWorkContext workContext)
        {
            OneParameter = (OneEnum)arguments[0];
            WorkContext = workContext;

        }

        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            //do your stuff....
             await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the attribute to Controller:

```
[MyFilter(OneEnum.OneValue)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{}
```

**No need** to register the attribute like below:

```
services.AddScoped<DoSomethingAttribute>();
```

Comment: Thank you. I removed the registration and it worked.

Comment: If my solution helped you,could you please accept as answer?